# How do you remove an orphaned inhibitor from gnome

Tags: gnome, gnome3

Gnome won't turn off monitors because of orphaned Inhibitor.  I had the gnome extension caffeine installed, and somehow it's left behind an orphaned inhibitor that is preventing gnome from turnning off my monitors due to inactivity.

Getting a list of inhibitors returns this

```
$ dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.GetInhibitors

method return time=1521481022.868053 sender=:1.14 -> destination=:1.1249 serial=3754 reply_serial=2
   array [
      object path "/org/gnome/SessionManager/Inhibitor5"
   ]
```

calling GetReason shows this

```
$ gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SessionManager --object-path /org/gnome/SessionManager/Inhibitor5 --method org.gnome.SessionManager.Inhibitor.GetReason

('Inhibit by Caffeine',)
```

I have found that there is an Unhibit method, but it takes a cookie that is lost.  How do I remove this orphaned inhibitor?

I have tried disabling the extension, but still no luck.

Comment: (+"Without logging out and back in again", I assume?)